# Why does console.log not show IEEE-754 floating point value of assigned var?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

I know that floating point values in JavaScript are stored with a binary base-2 format specified in IEEE 754. To me, this means that when I assign the literal value `.1` to a variable, the value actually stored will be 0.100000001490116119384765625 (or some high-precision number like that--my math may be wrong).

But counter to that assumption, the `console.log` of a stored value does not reflect this. The following code:

`var a = 0.1;
console.log(a);`

...when executed in Chrome, and probably other browsers, will output:

`0.1`

I would have expected it to be:

`0.100000001490116119384765625`

Does the value of `a` at this point hold `0.1` or `0.1000000...`? If the latter, then by what means does `console.log()` show `0.1`? I'm interested in what's going on under the hood here. (E.g. Is JS storing a text representation of the number in the variable?)

For you diligent admins that might be a little quick to "mark as duplicate", please note that I am asking the *opposite* of the more common question and variations "Why do I suddenly see these wacky high-precision numbers?"

Comment: Educated guess - the default precision of Number -> string conversions is insufficient to show these trailing digits.  This is pretty common in other languages (e.g. `printf` in C defaults to 6 decimal places).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JavaScript’s default formatting of floating-point values uses just enough decimal digits to uniquely distinguish the value from neighboring floating-point values.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386744/298225)

This question is a duplicate except it uses `console.log`, which is outside of JavaScript. The standard for JavaScript, the *ECMAScript 2017 Language Specification* does not mention `console`. This feature is provided by vendors as an extension. So each vendor may implement their own behavior. However, it is somewhat likely that using `console.log` with a `Number` will use the usual `ToString` behavior, resulting in the conversion explain in the answer linked above.

Comment: I *think* it's simpler than that - `console.log` probably just invokes string conversion on its arguments, as opposed to knowing anything special about numbers.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: To be complete, that needs to be shown, by citing the standard. I am on a phone at the moment, so finding things in the standard is awkward.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I thought about that. But in my code example, I first assigned the value to a variable to specifically prove that it wasn't console.log() trivially outputting a string conversion. It seems to me that the variable must store a string representation.

Comment: Okay, I can see now why it doesn't have to be stored as a string representation. Oliver, you gave another explanation which seems more plausible, the string conversion chops off after 6 digits or something like that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I read through your linked answer above, (nice work) and the ToString() operation from the ECMA spec explains the formatting I saw. Console logging seems outside of the ECMA standard. I found this informal spec https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer which would seem to indicate it's up to the browser implementation. And I would guess most (all?) of them would use the ECMA-defined ToString().

Comment: @ErikHermansen - I'm not sure I follow - what do you mean by "it wasn't console.log() trivially outputting a string conversion"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I think my logic was flawed in the "it wasn't console.log() trivially outputting" statement. I'm agreeing with what you said in the first comment at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You are right! Neverthless I never noticed that and can't explain it. Maybe some different does. I assume it's just not shown, because it would irritate many people and for most stuff it's not an issue.

```js
var a = 0.1;
console.log(a.toPrecision(21))
```

Comment: This should be a comment. Per the current [*ECMA-262 standard*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-number.prototype.toprecision), if the precision parameter is greater than 21, a range error exception is thrown. In [*ECMAScript 2019*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number.prototype.toprecision), it will be increased to 100 but you can't expect that to be widely implemented yet.