# Javascript Number type

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I'm working with JavaScript and trying to understand better how floating point numbers work and why .1 + .2 = .3000000000004 (or something close to that). I think I pretty much understand the why of that, I'm just confused on how I can set a variable equal to .3 at all.

I mean I know I can use var blah = .3, but I don't know how .3 can be stored in a floating point variable, I would expect that it would come out to be something like .299999999 or something since .3 can't be represented by negative powers of 2. If that makes sense.

I'm sure this question has been answered else where, but I can't find it. I can find lots of explanations on how floating point math and numbers work, but not this specific question. Or maybe you can store .3 in a floating point number and I'm just misunderstanding something.

Comment: `variable = 0.3`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question. I made an update.

Comment: It is simply impossible to represent the exact value of 0.3 in a floating point number which is defined on the basis of IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754).
The amount of exactly representable numbers is negligible compared to the amount of rational (not to talk of real) numbers which is infinite. Of course you can define a format which allows to represent 0.3 exactly but that only changes the selection of numbers which have a exact representation.

Comment: If your question is about why `console.log` still shows 0.3, then I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49711366/

Comment: Re why you see `0.3` instead of something else for `const v = 0.3; console.log(v);`, it's because the value in `v` is different from `0.30000000000000004`, but the algorithm for representing fractional numbers textually doesn't bother to show that because it doesn't have to to differentiate it from other representable number (but does with the other). Said algorithm is the result of years/decades of work with these imperfect-but-ever-so-useful floating point types, see "Note 3" [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring).

Comment: None of these numbers can be represented exactly in binary.  But when you just enter `0.1`, `0.2`, or `0.3` the error is in an insignificant bit, so you don't see it. However, when you combine them with arithmetic, the errors may accumulate into significant bits, and then you see them when you log the result.

Comment: BTW, when you use `0.3` directly, the value actually stored is `0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875`, which is (just) closer to `0.3` than `0.30000000000000004` is, which is why it's shown as `0.3` (rather than `0.30000000000000004` being shown that way; it's just that bit further away).

Comment: @user3618109 - It's crazy, and yet useful. :-)

Comment: @Elec1: Re “It is simply impossible to represent the exact value of 0.3 in a floating point number which is defined on the basis of IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)”: It is entirely possible using the decimal formats that IEEE 754 specifies.

Answer (score 0):

> …I don't know how .3 can be stored in a floating point variable…

It cannot. When `.3` appears in source code, it is converted to the nearest representable value, which is 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875, or, equivalently, 5,404,319,552,844,595•2<sup>−54</sup>.

In `.1 + .2`, `.1` is converted to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 (7,205,759,403,792,794•2<sup>−56</sup>), and `.2` is converted to 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125 (7,205,759,403,792,794•2<sup>−55</sup>).

Observe that the result for `.2`, 7,205,759,403,792,794•2<sup>−55</sup>, equals 2•7,205,759,403,792,794•2<sup>−56</sup> = 14,411,518,807,585,588•2<sup>−56</sup>. So, if we add the results for `.1` and `.2` mathematically, we get 21,617,278,211,378,382•2<sup>−56</sup>. However, the significand, 21,617,278,211,378,382, is too big to represent in the floating-point format. The format limits significands to 53 bits, and 2<sup>53</sup> is 9,007,199,254,740,992.

To make the significand small enough, we divide it by 4 and adjust the exponent by 2; 21,617,278,211,378,382•2<sup>−56</sup> = 5,404,319,552,844,595.5•2<sup>−54</sup>. However, significands in this form can only be integers, so we cannot get this as a floating-point result. The mathematical result of the addition must be rounded to fit in the format. 5,404,319,552,844,595.5 is equidistant between 5,404,319,552,844,595 and 5,404,319,552,844,596, and the rule is to round ties to an even number, so the floating-point result of adding `.1` and `.2` is 5,404,319,552,844,596•2<sup>−54</sup>, which is 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125.

Finally, we have to display that number. **By default, JavaScript does not display the actual values of floating-point numbers.** This is a shortcoming that contributes to misunderstanding floating-point. By default, JavaScript shows just enough digits to uniquely distinguish the floating-point number if you know the floating-point format. It produces the fewest number of digits (aside from an aesthetic leading `0` in `0.3…`) that will convert back to the floating-point number being displayed.

Above, we saw that converting `.3` to JavaScript’s floating-point format yields 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875. This means that, for 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125, JavaScript will not display `.3`, because `.3` converts to .2999…875, not to .3000…125. Also `.30`, `.300`, and `.3000` cannot be used. To get a numeral that will convert back to 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125, JavaScript produces `0.30000000000000004`.

In summary, in `.1 + .2`:

- `.1` is converted to the floating-point format, with rounding to fit in the format.
- `.2` is converted to the floating-point format, with rounding to fit in the format.
- `.1` and `.2` are added, with rounding to fit in the floating-point format.
- When printed, the result is converted to decimal, with enough digits to distinguish the value but fewer than needed to show the actual value, with rounding to the number of digits selected.

That is four roundings for one simple expression.