# JavaScript seems to be doing floating point wrong (compared to C)

Tags: javascript, c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

From everything I've been able to find online, JavaScript allegedly uses IEEE 754 doubles for its numbers, but I have found numbers that can work in C doubles, but not in JavaScript. For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double x = 131621703842267136.;
    printf("%lf\n", x);
}
```

prints `131621703842267136.000000` NOTE: IN AN EARLIER VERSION OF THE QUESTION I COPPIED THE WRONG NUMBER FOR C, but in JavaScript

```
console.log(131621703842267136)
```

outputs `131621703842267140`. From everything I've read online, both C doubles and JavaScript numbers are 64-bit floating point, so I am very confused why they would output different results. Any ideas?

Comment: `131621703842267136 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in JavaScript

Comment: while that is true, it still should be safe as it equals `6**22`, so the only non power of 2 bit is `3**22` which is much smaller, so it is storable as a double

Comment: For proof of this, C is able to store it in a double, so this question isn't a duplicate

Comment: The output `131621703737409536.000000` differs from the input `131621703842267136` on `C` in your question. Look at the last `4` digits of the integer part, for example.

Comment: afaik IEEE 754 defines both float and double, and javascript uses IEEE 754 doubles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: That's rather surprising output from C: only the first 9 digits are correct. Do you see the same output if you use "%f" instead of "%lf"? (The "l" isn't needed here.)

Comment: Anyway, independent of the C output, this is almost certainly just due to the way that JavaScript is *displaying* the float, not to do with the actual value that's stored. That is, the actual value in JS is almost certainly still `131621703842267136.0`, and it's being rounded for display purposes. You could verify this by (for example) computing `131621703842267136 - 131621703842200000`, which should show `67136.0`. (Note that 131621703842200000 is also exactly representable in IEEE 754 binary64 format.)

Comment: @VLAZ: The IEEE 754 standard specifies a variety of binary and decimal floating-point formats, including the binary64 format (informally, "double precision") that JavaScript is specified to use for all numbers, and that C implementations commonly use (but are not required to use) for the "double" type.

Comment: @MarkDickinson my mistake, then. If that's the case, I'm not sure what's happening. To be honest, this is getting out of my depth but JS does consider 131621703842267136 to be [over the maximum integer it can safely process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). `131621703842267136 + 1` yields `131621703842267140` and `(131621703842267136 + 1) - 131621703842200000` gives you `67136` - the same as `131621703842267136 - 131621703842200000`

Comment: I don't think you can compare these without mentioning what implementations do you use: Which C compiler? Which Javascript runtime?

Comment: @user694733: The JavaScript runtime is irrelevant since the behavior is specified by the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: Which C implementation are you using? Per my answer, it appears to be violating the C standard. Would you double-check that the C source in the question produces the output shown in the question?

Comment: @EricPostpischil An implementation with a 32bit `double`? https://wandbox.org/permlink/XYOaQfW8EueQXJOO

Comment: @Bob__: `double` is required to be able to preserve ten decimal digits. C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 12 says `DBL_DIG` must be at least ten, and it is the number of digits such that any decimal numeral with `DBL_DIG` significant decimal digits (such as 1.234567809•10^77) can be rounded to a `double` and back to a `DBL_DIG`-digit decimal numeral without change. A 32-bit double cannot satisfy that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript’s default conversion of a `Number` to a string produces just enough decimal digits to uniquely distinguish the `Number`. (This arises out of step 5 in clause 7.1.12.1 of the [ECMAScript 2018 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), which I explain a little [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386744/2982250).) Formatting via `console.log` is not covered by the ECMAScript specification, but likely the `Number` is converted to a string using the same rules as for `NumberToString`.

Since stopping at the ten’s digit, producing 131621703842267140, is enough to distinguish the floating-point number from its two neighboring representable values, 131621703842267120 and 131621703842267152, JavaScript stops there.

You can request more digits with `toPrecision`; the following produces “131621703842267136.000”:

```js
var x = 131621703842267136;
console.log(x.toPrecision(21))
```

(Note that 131621703842267136 is exactly representable in IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary format, which JavaScript uses for `Number`, and many C implementations use for `double`. So there are no rounding errors in this question due to the floating-point format. All changes result from conversions between decimal and floating-point.)

Prior to an edit at 2019-05-17 16:27:53 UTC, the question stated that a C program was showing “131621703737409536.000000” for 131621703842267136. That would not have been conforming to the C standard. The C standard is lax about its floating-point formatting requirements, but producing “131621703737409536.000000” for 131621703842267136 violates them. This is governed by this sentence in C 2018 (and 2011) 7.21.6.1 13:

> Otherwise, the source value is bounded by two adjacent decimal strings *L* < *U*, both having `DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits; the value of the resultant decimal string *D* should satisfy *L* ≤ *D* ≤ *U*, with the extra stipulation that the error should have a correct sign for the current rounding direction.

`DECIMAL_DIG` must be at least ten, by 5.2.4.2.2 12. The number 131621703**8**42267136 (bold marks the tenth digit) is bounded by the two adjacent ten-digit strings “131621703**8**00000000” and  “131621703**9**00000000”. The string “131621703**7**37409536.000000” is not between these.

This also cannot be a result of the C implementation using a different floating-point format for `double`, as 5.2.4.2.2 requires the format be sufficient to convert at least ten decimal digits to `double` and back to decimal without change to the value.