# JavaScript float not truncating correctly

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I am struggling to get the float number to show correctly. It works for the most part. For example, if I input 0.2 in "kWh" and 0.04 in "Hours used", it outputs 0.008 in "Total. However, when I change these values to 0.02 and 0.23, it outputs 0.046000000000000006. Why doesn't it output 0.046 instead? What am I missing here?

```js
<script>
        function calculate(){
            var amount = document.getElementById("kW").value;
            var amount = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
            var quantity = document.getElementById("hours").value;
            var quantity = parseFloat(quantity).toFixed(2);
            var total = amount * quantity;
            document.getElementById("total").value = total;
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="kWattsCol">
                <p><b>kWh</b></p>
                <input type="number" oninput="calculate()" id="kW" required>
            </div>

            <div class="hoursCol">
                <p><b>Hours used</b></p>
                <input type="number" oninput="calculate()" id="hours"required>
            </div>

            <div class="totalCol">
                <p><b>Total</b></p>
                <input type="text" id="total" readonly>
            </div>
```

Comment: @Quentin: Please do not promiscuously close floating-point questions as duplicates of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). This question involves issues of formatting floating-point numbers for display, which is a language choice (when defaults are used), and is not strictly a property of floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil question has been reopened, do you want to put a nice explainer in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does JavaScript determine the number of digits to produce when formatting floating-point values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384477/how-does-javascript-determine-the-number-of-digits-to-produce-when-formatting-fl)

Answer (score 1):

### Correction

> … when I change these values to 0.02 and 0.23, it outputs 0.046000000000000006…

The floating-point product of these would be a number near .0046, not near .046. So I suspect the actual input was “0.2” and “0.23”. The answer below proceeds on this basis.

### Discussion

When default JavaScript formatting of numbers is used, it produces just enough significant digits to uniquely distinguish the floating-point number from its neighbors in the floating-point format. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386744/298225) describes this further.

When the input “0.2” is converted to the floating-point format JavaScript uses (IEEE-754 binary64, also called “double precision”), the result is 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125. When “0.04” is converted, the result is 0.040000000000000000832667268468867405317723751068115234375. When these are multiplied, the result is 0.008000000000000000166533453693773481063544750213623046875. (This includes rounding of the real-number-arithmetic product to the nearest value representable in the floating-point format.)

Here is the neighbor before the result, the result, and the neighbor after the result:

```
0.00799999999999999843180997771696638665162026882171630859375
0.008000000000000000166533453693773481063544750213623046875
0.00800000000000000190125692967058057547546923160552978515625
```

Observe that .008 is closest to the middle of these, the arithmetic result. That means, when 0.008000000000000000166533453693773481063544750213623046875 is formatted for display, we only need to produce “0.008” to identify it.

In the second case, converting “0.23” yields 0.2300000000000000099920072216264088638126850128173828125, and then the product is 0.046000000000000006161737786669618799351155757904052734375.

Looking at the neighbor before, the result, and the neighbor after, we have:

```
0.04599999999999999922284388276239042170345783233642578125
0.046000000000000006161737786669618799351155757904052734375
0.0460000000000000131006316905768471769988536834716796875
```

Observe that .046 is closer to the neighbor before rather than to the result; it differs by less than one in the nineteenth decimal place, whereas the result differs by more than 6. Therefore, to identify the result, we need to produce “0.046000000000000006”.

Comment: Thanks!  Hopefully will be linked by other people